# How to tell python that the unexpected variable type passing to a function is correct in the context

Tags: python, unit-testing, annotations, pytest

I'm new to Python 3 and testing with pytest. Sometimes, I want to test that my function raises TypeError or AssertionError when I provide it with type that it is not supposed to process. Consider this simple example:

```
import pytest


def concatenate_string(first_string: str, second_string: str) -> str:
    return first_string + second_string


def test_concatenate_string_raises_type_error():
    with pytest.raises(TypeError) as pytest_wrapped_e:
        concatenate_string('abc', 1)
    assert e.type == TypeError
```

My problem here is, that when I provide the integer 1 to the function concatenate_string, PyCharm warns me about unexpected type assigned. I know this is a correct behaviour, but is there a way to tell the program (e.g. by some other annotation): "I know what I'm doing, I really want to have this type here, don't warn be about it."?

I know I can just tell the editor to ignore it, but it feels somehow wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#compatibility-with-other-uses-of-function-annotations):

```
concatenate_string('abc', 1)  # type: ignore
```

this should suppress the type checking for that line

Comment: sorry I first misunderstood the problem, deleted the original answer as it was unrelated

Comment: I think this should work with most of the typecheckers. However, it seems that in Pycharm (2020.2), this doesn't work as `concatenate_string('abc', 1)  # type: ignore` still shows the same warning. I found out that in PyCharm, the same can be done by `# noinspection PyTypeChecker`, which must be above the line of code it should ignore.